# set file permissions in one directory to match another

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu-12.04, file-permissions

Using bash or Python how do you :

- Specify a baseline directory (dir-a)
- Compare the contents to another directory (dir-b)
- Where a file/dir exists in both dir-a and dir-b set permissions of the dir-b file to match the permissions of dir-a

So in the following directories (and their child directories) where one file/dir matches another (eg ./SVN_SANDBOX/db and ./SVN_TEST1/db) I'd like to set the permissions for ./SVN_SANDBOX/db to be made equal to those for ./SVN_TEST1/db

```
glauc@foofoofo:~/devadmin/svn/SVN_SANDBOX$ ls -l
total 28
dr-xr-xr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:16 conf
dr-xr-xr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:16 dav
dr-xr-xr-x 5 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:16 db
-r--r--r-- 1 glauc glauc    2 Jul  2 21:16 format
dr-xr-xr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:16 hooks
dr-xr-xr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:16 locks
-r--r--r-- 1 glauc glauc  234 Jul  2 21:16 README.txt
glauc@foofoofo:~/devadmin/svn/SVN_SANDBOX$ cd ../SVN_TEST1
glauc@foofoofo:~/devadmin/svn/SVN_TEST1$ ls -l
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:23 conf
drwxrwsr-x 6 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:23 db
-r--r--r-- 1 glauc glauc    2 Jul  2 21:23 format
drwxrwxr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:23 hooks
drwxrwxr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Jul  2 21:23 locks
-rw-rw-r-- 1 glauc glauc  229 Jul  2 21:23 README.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be easy as using get/setfacl (check the generated file has relative paths):

```
cd dir-a && getfacl -R . > /permissions.acl
cd dir-b && setfacl --restore=/permissions.acl
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a lot easier in bash than in Python, especially if you can use platform-specific tools, especially tools that are guaranteed by Ubuntu 12 but not by linux in general… (See DRC's answer.)

But if you want to do it in Python, it's not that hard:

```
import os
import sys

srcdir, dstdir = sys.argv[1:]

paths = (os.path.join(srcdir, name) for name in os.listdir(srcdir))    
modes = {name: os.lstat(path).st_mode for path in paths}

for name in os.listdir(dstdir):
    try:
        mode = modes[name]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        os.lchmod(os.path.join(dstdir, name), mode)
```

---

If you want it to be recursive, just use `flat_walk` instead of `listdir`, which you can define like this:

```
def flat_walk(path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            yield os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```